# Workfront Custom Filtering

Tags: filtering, attask

I'm trying to create a filter to find a missing task in several Workfront plans. I have tried system filters with no luck.

I can filter if missing a field but not a task.

I am using the web interface. I am looking for a task with a specific name (i.e. Identify External Resources), that should be in multiple project plans, and I want to find plans without that task listed.

Comment: Please update your question with more detail. Are you using the API or the web interface? What do you mean by a missing task? Are you looking for a task with a specific name that's in multiple project and you want to find projects without it?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are:

- Find all projects
- Filter for projects that do not contain the task 'identify external resources'

My assumptions are:

- You want ALL projects that don't contain the named task
- Your criteria is that the project either has the task or doesn't (you don't care if has 1 task of that name or 100)

The solution is:

- Create a project-level report
- Go into the filter tab
- Switch to text mode and add the following:

> ```
> tasks:name=identify external resources
> tasks:name_Mod=cinotcontains
> ```

This will find all projects that don't have a task named 'identify external resources'. You can combine this with additional filter to add other tasks and/or status filters.

Comment: Is there any way to apply "AND" and "OR" combination query. As I want to fetch data on a user-defined query and user define that query in form of MySql query. So I want to convert that query to a format that understood by workfront.

Comment: Since you asked this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633424/how-to-integrate-nested-and-or-conditions-to-the-workfront-query/49633782 I'll point this comment in that direction.